# Spring RestController doesn't work propely when get two or more POST requests in same millisecond

Tags: spring, spring-boot, controller, milliseconds

I have a problem with Spring RestController. Expected behavior: receive a POST (some xml content in body), do some things with it: parse xml, decode Base64, XSLT transform, write to database.

Each action (parse xml, decode Base64, XSLT transform, write to database) is a separate bean with scope PROTOTYPE. In my log I see:

1. receive content:,
2. parse xml, 2.OK
3. decode Base64, 3.OK
4. XSLT transform, 4.OK
5. write to database, 5.OK.

When I get two requests in same millisecond I get an error in my log:

> Error parsing xml - null

In log I see:

1. receive content:,
2. receive content:,
3. parse xml,
4. parse xml, 1.OK,
5. decode Base64, 2.OK
6. XSLT transform, 3.OK
7. write to database, 4.OK.

Second request disappears.
I expect to have a big incoming traffic. My code is in Spring Boot, I use standard Spring 4 style (@RestController, @PostMapping), define a separate bean for each action. Could anybody help?

Comment: It is hard to predict what went wrong without looking at the actual code. There could be several reasons behind this. Can you post the controller method code?

Comment: You should investigate load balancing with Ribbon through/with ZUUL and Eureka. https://spring.io/guides/gs/client-side-load-balancing/